# Postgres: How to do Composite keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, composite-key

I cannot understand the syntax error in creating a composite key. It may be a logic error, because I have tested many varieties.

**How do you create composite keys in Postgres?**

```
CREATE TABLE tags
     (
              (question_id, tag_id) NOT NULL,
              question_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
              tag_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
              tag1 VARCHAR(20),
              tag2 VARCHAR(20),
              tag3 VARCHAR(20),
              PRIMARY KEY(question_id, tag_id),
              CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_tag UNIQUE (question_id, tag_id)
     );
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
    LINE 3:               (question_id, tag_id) NOT NULL,
                          ^
```

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Your compound `PRIMARY KEY` specification already does what you want.  Omit the line that's giving you a syntax error, and omit the redundant `CONSTRAINT` (already implied), too:

```
 CREATE TABLE tags
      (
               question_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
               tag_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
               tag1 VARCHAR(20),
               tag2 VARCHAR(20),
               tag3 VARCHAR(20),
               PRIMARY KEY(question_id, tag_id)
      );

NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "tags_tag_id_seq" for serial column "tags.tag_id"
    NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "tags_pkey" for table "tags"
    CREATE TABLE
    pg=> \d tags
                                         Table "public.tags"
       Column    |         Type          |                       Modifiers       
    -------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
     question_id | integer               | not null
     tag_id      | integer               | not null default nextval('tags_tag_id_seq'::regclass)
     tag1        | character varying(20) |
     tag2        | character varying(20) |
     tag3        | character varying(20) |
    Indexes:
        "tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (question_id, tag_id)
```

Comment: How would you implement a contraint like "CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_refences UNIQUE REFERENCE FROM tag_id TO (tag1, tag2, tag3)"?

Comment: @Masi, I don't think I understand enough of what you're trying to model here, and, to be frank, the columns `tag1` through `tag3` suggest to me that you might have further design refinements to do.  Perhaps a separate question, with a natural language description of your model and a few example records, would help.

Answer (score 28):

The error you are getting is in line 3. i.e. it is not in

```
CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_tag UNIQUE (question_id, tag_id)
```

but earlier:

```
CREATE TABLE tags
     (
              (question_id, tag_id) NOT NULL,
```

Correct table definition is like pilcrow showed.

And if you want to add unique on tag1, tag2, tag3 (which sounds very suspicious), then the syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    question_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tag_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    tag1 VARCHAR(20),
    tag2 VARCHAR(20),
    tag3 VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(question_id, tag_id),
    UNIQUE (tag1, tag2, tag3)
);
```

or, if you want to have the constraint named according to your wish:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    question_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tag_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    tag1 VARCHAR(20),
    tag2 VARCHAR(20),
    tag3 VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(question_id, tag_id),
    CONSTRAINT some_name UNIQUE (tag1, tag2, tag3)
);
```