# Postgresql Increment if exist or Create a new row

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have a simple table like that:

```
+------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+
|id (serial) | date(date) | customer_fk(integer) | value(integer) |
+------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

I want to use every row like a daily accumulator, if a customer value arrives
and if doesn't exist a record for that customer and date, then create a new row for that customer and date, but if exist only increment the value.

I don't know how implement something like that, I only know how increment a value using SET, but more logic is required here. Thanks in advance.

I'm using version 9.4

Comment: `"more logic is required here"` I'm afraid that more information is also required.  Are you using a language along with Postgresql or did you have in mind to use a procedure?

Comment: In order to get my requirement is needed apply more logic, I don't know if is possible do something like that with a procedure.

Comment: I think will be better using Postgresql only.

Comment: You don't need the id field. I just changed my answer. Your primary key should be the date and customer_fk to trigger the ON CONFLICT resolution part of the insert syntax.

Comment: @centijo Could be the date field the primary key? because that field will not be unique..

Comment: @Goku You need a composite primary key. The primary key would be made up of the date and customer_fk. That's what makes it unique. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285967/postgres-how-to-do-composite-keys

Comment: @Goku Are you able to use a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80237/discussion-between-centijo-and-goku).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like what you are wanting to do is an UPSERT.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html

In this type of query, you update the record if it exists or you create a new one if it does not. The key in your table would consist of `customer_fk` and `date`.

This would be a normal insert, but with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET value = value + 1`.

**NOTE: This only works as of Postgres 9.5. It is not possible in previous versions. For versions prior to 9.1, the only solution is two steps. For 9.1 or later, a CTE may be used as well.**

**For earlier versions of Postgres,** you will need to perform an `UPDATE` first with `customer_fk` and `date` in the `WHERE` clause. From there, check to see if the number of affected rows is `0`. If it is, then do the `INSERT`. The only problem with this is there is a chance of a race condition if this operation happens twice at nearly the same time (common in a web environment) since the `INSERT` has a chance of failing for one of them and your count will always have a chance of being slightly off.

If you are using Postgres 9.1 or above, you can use an updatable CTE as cleverly pointed out here: [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/8702291#8702291)
This solution is less likely to result in a race condition since it's executed in one step.

```
WITH new_values (date::date, customer_fk::integer, value::integer) AS (
  VALUES 
     (today, 24, 1)
),
upsert AS ( 
    UPDATE mytable m 
        SET value = value + 1
    FROM new_values nv
    WHERE m.date = nv.date AND m.customer_fk = nv.customer_fk
    RETURNING m.*
)
INSERT INTO mytable (date, customer_fk, value)
SELECT date, customer_fk, value
FROM new_values
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM upsert up 
                  WHERE up.date = new_values.date
                  AND up.customer_fk = new_values.customer_fk)
```

This contains two CTE tables. One contains the data you are inserting (`new_values`) and the other contains the results of an `UPDATE` query using those values (`upsert`). The last part uses these two tables to check if the records in `new_values` are not present in `upsert`, which would mean the `UPDATE` failed, and performs an `INSERT` to create the record instead.

---

As a side note, if you were doing this in another SQL engine that conforms to the standard, you would use a `MERGE` query instead. [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL) ]

Comment: PostgreSQL has (the equivalent of) `UPSERT` now?  Cool!  Any idea when this arrived?

Comment: It's in 9.5-dev. There's no UPSERT/MERGE in stable versions of Postgres. How long have we been complaining about this?

Comment: So bad I'm using Postgresql 9.4

Comment: If you could use anything else, this would be easy. But then, you probably wouldn't be asking on SO either. ;)